# making valgrind able to read user input when c++ needs it

Tags: c++, user-input, valgrind

I am trying to run my c++ program with valgrind, however I have some points in the program which require user input from stdin, but when i run with valgrind, it wont let the user input anything for the program, is there a way around this?

Been searching all around but have not found the answer.

Comment: you should expand what you mean by valgrind won't let the user input anything. I've used valgrind to debug programs that read from stdin numerous times.

Comment: what i mean is, i start my program and it needs user input to start, (entering a number in stdin), it also outputs some text to the console...the text does not show, and i cannot enter any input on the console when running with valgrind...

Comment: @Daneil boil this down to a small reproducer and post the code here. I do not see that behavior, even when debugging large applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I found this in the man pages:

```
--input-fd=<number> [default: 0, stdin]
              Specify the file descriptor to use for reading  input  from  the
              user.  This  is  used whenever valgrind needs to prompt the user
              for a decision.
```

What happens if you specify a different fd (say, 3) for valgrind to use for input?

Comment: I have tried but nothing, i should probably also mention that i dont get any output to the screen either when valgrind is running

Comment: @Daniel: Read this and see if it's your problem: http://www.freelists.org/post/programmingblind/Solved-Problem-using-valgrind

Comment: i guess he is redirecting output to another console, unfortunatly in the enviroment i am in I do not have permition to do that.. is there no other way?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a linux example where a cgi program (./myexe) reads from stdin.  We put the input into a file mystdin.  So valgrind can read input from the terminal, we do the --input-fd=3 and tell the shell to redirect /dev/tty to file descriptor 3.  So that we can control gdb, we add a redirect of stdin from /dev/tty in the --db-command paramater to valgrind.  This is probably a worse case example.  Hope it helps.

```
valgrind --input-fd=3 --db-command='gdb -nw %f %p < /dev/tty' --db-attach=yes ./myexe < mystdin  3</dev/tty
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer, in my case it solved my need.

**Edit**: I was wrong, this solution is not valid. Read @Hasturkun comment.

I have a program that asks the user to enter a password through the prompt:

```
./my_program
Password:
```

I write a password, for example "*abcd1234*" and press enter, the program ends successfully. Ok, but ... how can I do a memory check of my program using **Valgrind**, and the prompt doesn't wait for me to enter a password and press enter?

I simply put `echo "fake-password"` with a pipe before the exec of my program, like this:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all -v echo "fake-password" | ./my_program > /dev/null
```

In this way, the program will not ask the user to enter any data at the prompt and the string "*fake-password*" will be sent by the stdIn to the program in the same way as if you had written it and pressed Enter.

This is the result:

```
==907664== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==907664== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==907664== Using Valgrind-3.15.0-608cb11914-20190413 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==907664== Command: echo fake-password
==907664== 
--907664-- Valgrind options:
--907664--    --tool=memcheck
--907664--    --leak-check=full
--907664--    --show-leak-kinds=all
--907664--    -v
...
...
--907664-- REDIR: 0x49f2650 (libc.so.6:__mempcpy_avx_unaligned_erms) redirected to 0x4843660 (mempcpy)
--907664-- REDIR: 0x49f2670 (libc.so.6:__memcpy_avx_unaligned_erms) redirected to 0x48429f0 (memmove)
--907664-- REDIR: 0x4901850 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x483c9d0 (free)
==907664== 
==907664== HEAP SUMMARY:
==907664==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==907664==   total heap usage: 31 allocs, 31 frees, 8,161 bytes allocated
==907664== 
==907664== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==907664== 
==907664== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I hope it works for you, it worked for me.

Comment: You just ran valgrind on `echo fake-password`, I'm guessing that wasn't what you wanted to do.

Comment: Ops! You are right @Hasturkun, I was wrong. The message from "total heap usage" has confused me, since it is almost the same result that I expect from my program. Now I'm curious how this would be done Any ideas to get this right? Thank you for the correction ;)

Comment: Generally, if you're not running Valgrind with the `--gen-suppressions=yes` flag, it shouldn't steal away your input. As the other answers indicated, you can switch away what Valgrind reads from. Assuming that `stdin` is still in place, you can pipe your data right through Valgrind, e.g. `echo hello world | valgrind...` since it won't be reading `stdin` itself.