# Valgrind C: How to input string from stdio

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

This is code:

```
char* inputString(){
    int n = 5;
    int size = n;
    char* const_str = (char*)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));
    char* substring = (char*)malloc((n+n)*sizeof(char)); /*here*/
    char*p;
    while((fgets(const_str,n,stdin)!=NULL)&&(strchr(const_str,'\n')==NULL)){
        strcat(substring,const_str);
        size += n;
        substring = (char*)realloc(substring,size*sizeof(char)); /*here*/
        }
    strcat(substring,const_str);
    size += n;
    substring = (char*)realloc(substring,size*sizeof(char)); /*here*/
    /*
    printf("<%s> is \n",const_str);
    printf("%s is \n",substring);
    printf("%d is \n",size);
    */
    if ((p=strchr(substring,'\n'))!=NULL){
        p[0]='\0';
    }
    if(feof(stdin)){
        changeToFull();
    }
    return substring;
}
```

and it will not be work on valgrind.

I guess, that i have memory leak here, but, i can't see any good solution to rewrite this function for valgrind.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I found this on a question on SO:

```
--input-fd=<number> [default: 0, stdin]
          Specify the file descriptor to use for reading  input  from  the
          user.  This  is  used whenever valgrind needs to prompt the user
          for a decision.
```

Original question here: [making valgrind able to read user input when c++ needs it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973921/making-valgrind-able-to-read-user-input-when-c-needs-it)

EDIT:

So for your case, you may try:

```
mkfifo /tmp/abcd
exec 3</tmp/abcd
valgrind_command...... --input-fd=3
```

& in another terminal, use

```
cat > /tmp/abcd
```

Comment: See the edit...
Also see the 2 answers on the question link I posted.